# How to use Tasker to kill apps on/after device boot?

Tags: boot, tasker, task-management

I have several apps auto start at boot, and it's really not necessary. So I'm trying to use Tasker to kill them on/after device boot.

Tasker has a "Event - Device Boot" option, but it seems that does not work. Tasker just cannot catch this event.

I'v also tried to trigger the profile when another app (which starts after Tasker) starts. It works but the problem is that each time the app starts, Taker performs the action, but I only need the task to be performed once.

Can anyone think of any trick to do this?

PS: please no recommendation on third-party apps or permission change method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your restriction (no 3rd party apps) will keep a better fitting answer away, I'd say. What you describe is a task not for Tasker, but for... oh, I shall not mention it you wrote...

Your problem is most likely that *Tasker* very well catches the `boot_completed` event, but the apps to kill have been waiting for the same. So when *Tasker* looks to kill them, they're not yet started. Your Task thus finishes without anything done, and *Whoop!* then the unwanted apps start.

So if you really want to do this via Tasker, I'd insert a `Tasker -> Wait` at the very beginning of the task. Play with the values, start with 15s and increase in 15s steps until either it works or your reach a point where it's unlikely to work (say e.g. 2 min, or you see the apps have started and your Task didn't kill them).

If that still doesn't work, combine it with switching the condition: In case *Tasker* really cannot catch the `boot_completed` (well, *Tasker* itself is started then), switch to "monitoring start", and start over with 15s wait again.

Finally, though you didn't want 3rd party apps, just in case you re-think that: [Autorun Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun) does this job quite fine, without any hazzle. On rooted devices, it even can disable other intents than just `boot_completed` listeners.

Comment: Thanks Izzy, the problem is just like what you guessed. I didn't insert `wait`, and the app I was about to kill actually started after Tasker performed the action. Now everything's fine with a 15 seconds delay.

Comment: Congrats! Yeah, that's the usual "missing thing" with certain tasks: timing can be tricky ;) But luckily we've got this one solved -- enjoy Tasker :)

Comment: FYI, Autorun Manager seems to have turned bad, very bad (ads, not updated, dubious methods to force you use pro, and a lot of bugs).

Comment: @vaab I didn't use it for a long time – and back when I used it, I've used the pro version. Sad to hear it turned bad – though I don't see it having too many or aggressive ad modules (just AdMob). Anyway, for permanent use one should take the pro – though of course bad behavior is not a thing to convince.